# Back to a fragment from fragmentActivity in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm trying to get back to a fragment from a fragmentActivity, but it is not working, I'm getting NullPointerException, When I hit cancel I need to update the previous fragment. How can I get back to a fragment and update it? don't know why this is happening.

```
public class AddEscolas extends FragmentActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addescola);

        mSessao = new SecurePreferences(AddEscolas.this, "sessao");

        pesquisa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campo_pesquisa);
        nomeEscola = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nomeEscola);
        logradouro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.endereco);
        cidade = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cidade);
        procura = pesquisa.getText();

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(pesquisa.getWindowToken(), 0);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

        findViewById(R.id.btnProcurar).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Pesquisa().execute();
                mFerramentas.hideKeyboard(AddEscolas.this, pesquisa);

            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.btnCancelar).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
            }
        });



    }
}
```

FragmentClass :

```
public class EscolasFragment extends Fragment {



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_escolas, container, false);

        ImageView add = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.add);


        mSessao = new SecurePreferences(getActivity(), "sessao");

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent addIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddEscolas.class);
                startActivity(addIntent);

            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no sense in what you are doing... you should read through the Android docs about fragments

Comment: can you please provide the stacktrace of the null pointer exception

Comment: are you trying to start Activity from inside the fragment. That's confusing because the fragment is a part of the activity, how it can start it. Fragment can talk to activity using callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you just need to call finish(), like this:

```
  findViewById(R.id.btnCancelar).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                finish();
            }
        });
```

The reason for the NullPointerException maybe is that the layout id of R.id.content_frame could not be found in the AddEscolas activity.

If you need to update the EscolasFragment fragment after the AddEscolas activity exits, you may do as follow steps:

1. use startActivity() from the EscolarFragment fragment to call the AddEscolas activity.
2. use onActivityResult() in the activity containing the EscolarFragment fragment  to extract result returned by the AddEscolas activity.
3. use onResume() in the EscolarFragment fragment to update the UI.

Comment: I can't simply call finish, I need to update the EscolaFragment when I back to it

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong idea about what FragmentActivity is. Activities host fragments. You cant go  to fragment without having activity. Read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Null pointer exception comes from

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

you need to give instance to 'fragment'. Somehing like:

```
Fragment fragment = new YourFragment();
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply call `onBackPressed();` in the FragmentActivity.